# Using matplotlib to create a histogram on Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to create a simple histogram for a csv file named "count_backers.csv". The code that I have so far is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py
import csv

def make_hist(csv_filepath):
    data = open(csv_filepath)
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    column = []
    for row in data:
        column.append(row)
    plt.hist(column)
    plt.title("Number of Backers")
    plt.xlabel("Frequency")
    plt.ylabel("Value")
    plt.show()

# fig = plt.gcf()
# plot_url = py.plot_mpl(fig, filename='backers_histogram')

backer_data = r"C:/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming/count_backers.csv"
make_hist(backer_data)
```

I began learning python using Learn Python the Hard Way, and I am used to executing python files from PowerShell. However, I was struggling to install and build matplotlib on Windows and for the sake of time I decided to install it on Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu. After I was able to get that working I am now getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "histogram.py", line 22, in <module>
    make_hist(backer_data)
  File "histogram.py", line 7, in make_hist
    data = open(csv_filepath)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming/count_backers.csv'
```

I have tried several different versions of the filepath including:

```
backer_data = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\user\Programming\count_backers.csv"
backer_data = "mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming/count_backers.csv"
backer_data = r"mnt\c\Users\user\Documents\user\Programming\count_backers.csv"
```

These produce the following errors respectively:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\user\\Programming\\count_backers.csv'
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming/count_backers.csv'
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mnt\\c\\Users\\user\\Documents\\user\\Programming\\count_backers.csv'
```

When I use `ls` on the specified directory though it does show the file being there:

```
smidem@JealousHippo:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming$ ls
column_avg.py  count_backers.csv  histogram.py  pledged.csv
```

I'm pretty confused as to why it is unable to locate this file and any help would be greatly appreciated.

With l0b0's help I changed `backer_data` to `backer_data = "/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming/count_backers.csv"` but I am now receiving this in response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "histogram.py", line 22, in <module>
    make_hist(backer_data)
  File "histogram.py", line 12, in make_hist
    plt.hist(column)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2947, in hist
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 928, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 578, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 527, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 84, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 92, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1871, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Install Anaconda Python Distribution (google it) which will solve all your python issues in windows.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/user/Programming/count_backers.csv"` is a **relative** path starting at the current working directory, which most likely is not the filesystem root. Try starting the path with a slash.

Comment: That did work, but I'm now getting some different errors. I edited my question to show the new errors.

Comment: That is a completely different problem. Please post a new question.